# TensorFlow PoolAllocator huge number of requests

Tags: python, tensorflow

using Tensorflow r0.9/r.10 I get the following message, that makes me worried I've set my neural network model in the wrong way.

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:244] PoolAllocator: After 6206792 get requests, put_count=6206802 evicted_count=5000 eviction_rate=0.000805568 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.000806536
```

The network I use is similar to AlexNet/VGG-M, I create the variables and the ops in a function called once, and then I just loop over multiple epochs calling the same omptimizer, loss and prediction function for each mini-batch iteration.

Another thing that makes me worried is that the network can be unstable when using a large batch size: it runs fine for few epochs, and then it goes out of memory (trying to allocate...).

Is there any way to check if there is something wrong and what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an info-level log statement (the "I" prefix). It does not necessarily mean that anything is wrong: however, the pool allocator (a cache for allocations) is finding that it frequently has to fall back on the underlying allocator. This may indicate memory pressure.

For your instability problem: as you observe, large batches can lead to out-of-memory errors. There is some nondeterminism to operator scheduling, which is why you may not see it fail every time. Try lowering your batch size until you consistently no longer see out of memory errors.

Comment: Thanks @peter-hawkins, I did that already and I manage to have a stable training, but this does not satisfy my curiosity. I guess what would be nice to do is to see which operation allocates the most memory.. some times ago I found that the LRN operator was not GPU implemented, so it would work only on the CPU: that was easy to stop, given the high CPU usage. In the case of an operator generating more and more variables, what would be the best profiling actions (any suggestion is welcome!).